# Transfer my sharepoint application from one environment to another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, deployment

I have SharePoint 2013 server & SQL server 2008 r2 inside my development and UAT environments. Currently inside my development environment I did the following main tasks:-

1. I have created a new **sharePoint Application** that uses NTL authentication, and which does not allow anonymous login (no login page).
2. I have created a new **Team site** collection named “Intranet” under the default managed path for the new SP application. ...//sharepointdev/sites/Intranet/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/
3. I have created a new **managed path** named “discussionforum”.
4. I have created a new **Community site** collection under the new managed path:- ...//sharepointdev/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/
5. Next step is that I added the following **App parts** to my team site home page:-

   - Document library.
   - Announcements.
   - Prompted links.
   - Content editor web part.
   - 4 calendars that are overlayed.

**I have finished my development, and now I need to transfer all my above work from my development machine to my UAT machine? So how I can do this?**

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. You can back up the development Site Collection by using the [SharePoint Central Administration website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx#proc2) or [Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx#proc1).
2. Then in your UAT machine, create a SharePoint Application that uses NTL authentication.
3. Then create a new "Team Site Collection" in your UAT SharePoint Application.
4. Then using the backup file, you can [restore the Site Collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748655.aspx#PS) in the UAT SharePoint Application.

hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for the help. i did a quick test, and seems it work well, but i am not sure why you mentioned that i have to create a new "Team Site Collection" in my UAT SharePoint Application?. i  restore the site collection to a new location (where no site collection exsisits), an SP automatically created the team site for me ? am i doing the right thing ?

Comment: If you look at the "Restore-SPSite" command it will ask for the URL of the Site Collection you want to restore. If you dont have a site collection, then where you will restore your backup file.

Comment: if i do not have a site collection, SP will automatically create the site collection. i have tried it .